# How to Make Customize Error Page in Webview Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, sdk

I am new to flutter. Currently i am building the web app that using flutter webview plugin but i have a question about the internet connectivity. When users doesnt have a connection that app gives a default error page like

```
Webpage not available
The webpage at https://covid19.who.int/ could be not be loaded because:
net:::ERR_Internet_disconnected
```

How to use custom code to show custom error page like to hide url? My proper code is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';
import 'package:covidwho/layout/myAppBar.dart';

class Who extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WhoState createState() => _WhoState();
}

class _WhoState extends State<Who> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: MyAppBar(),
      body: Container(
        child: WebviewScaffold(
          url: "https://covid19.who.int/",
          withJavascript: true,
          withLocalStorage: true,
          hidden: true,
          initialChild: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                ),
              )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked this one : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59110720/7666442

Comment: Yes i tried to use that plugin but this plugin also has a same problem as my old flutter_webview_plugin. When internet connection is down its gives me error page with trex game but before that its clearly seeing error page. Its just for one or more second but it is. Sequence is like that:


Open App - Close internet - Open any button (while internet is off) it gives same error page include  url and after that its redirect me to customized no connection page with trex. Any solution about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you need to implement

- `Stream<String> onError` webview event.
- Don't forget to dispose webview `flutterWebviewPlugin.dispose()`

Here is a code sample

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';

String selectedUrl = 'https://flutter.io';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyHomePage());
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  // Instance of WebView plugin
  final flutterWebViewPlugin = FlutterWebviewPlugin();

  // On destroy stream
  StreamSubscription _onDestroy;

  //  On Http error
  StreamSubscription<WebViewHttpError> _onHttpError;
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    flutterWebViewPlugin.launch(selectedUrl);

    // Add a listener to on destroy WebView, so you can make came actions.
    _onDestroy = flutterWebViewPlugin.onDestroy.listen((_) {
      if (mounted) {
        // Actions like show a info toast.
        _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(content: const Text('Webview Destroyed')));
      }
    });

    _onHttpError =
        flutterWebViewPlugin.onHttpError.listen((WebViewHttpError error) {
      if (mounted) {
        //do your customization here
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Every listener should be canceled, the same should be done with this stream.
    _onDestroy.cancel();
    _onHttpError.cancel();
    flutterWebViewPlugin.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**I would like to share with you the code I use to show custom pages at the time of flutter web errors.**

Full project link https://github.com/K3rimoff/flutter-custom-web-error-page

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
import '../../components/back_pressed.dart';
import '../../theme/colors.dart';
import '../error/error.dart';

class WebScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<WebScreen> createState() => _WebScreenState();
}

class _WebScreenState extends State<WebScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _animationController;
  InAppWebViewController? _webViewController;
  PullToRefreshController? _refreshController;

  bool _isLoading = false, _isVisible = false, _isOffline = false;

  // 0 - Everything is ok, 1 - http or other error fixed
  int _errorCode = 0;
  final BackPressed _backPressed = BackPressed();

  Future<void> checkError() async {
    //Hide CircularProgressIndicator
    _isLoading = false;

    //Check Network Status
    ConnectivityResult result = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();

    //if Online: hide offline page and show web page
    if (result != ConnectivityResult.none) {
      if (_isOffline == true) {
        _isVisible = false; //Hide Offline Page
        _isOffline = false; //set Page type to error
      }
    }

    //If Offline: hide web page show offline page
    else {
      _errorCode = 0;
      _isOffline = true; //Set Page type to offline
      _isVisible = true; //Show offline page
    }

    // If error is fixed: hide error page and show web page
    if (_errorCode == 1) _isVisible = false;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 2));
    _animationController.repeat();
    _refreshController = PullToRefreshController(
      onRefresh: () => _webViewController!.reload(),
      options: PullToRefreshOptions(
          color: Colors.white, backgroundColor: Colors.black87),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
                InAppWebView(
                  onWebViewCreated: (controller) =>
                      _webViewController = controller,
                  initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                      crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                    supportZoom: false,
                  )),
                  initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
                      url: Uri.parse(
                          "https://google.com")), // For http error: change to wrong url : https://google.com/404/
                  pullToRefreshController: _refreshController,
                  onLoadStart: (controller, url) {
                    setState(() {
                      _isLoading = true; //Show CircularProgressIndicator
                    });
                  },
                  onLoadStop: (controller, url) {
                    _refreshController!.endRefreshing();
                    checkError(); //Check Error type: offline or other error
                  },
                  onLoadError: (controller, url, code, message) {
                    // Show
                    _errorCode = code;
                    _isVisible = true;
                  },
                  onLoadHttpError: (controller, url, statusCode, description) {
                    _errorCode = statusCode;
                    _isVisible = true;
                  },
                ),
                //Error Page
                Visibility(
                  visible: _isVisible,
                  child: ErrorScreen(
                      isOffline: _isOffline,
                      onPressed: () {
                        _webViewController!.reload();
                        if (_errorCode != 0) {
                          _errorCode = 1;
                        }
                      }),
                ),
                //CircularProgressIndicator
                Visibility(
                  visible: _isLoading,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive(
                    valueColor: _animationController.drive(
                      ColorTween(
                          begin: circularProgressBegin,
                          end: circularProgressEnd),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          floatingActionButton: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {
                  _errorCode = 1;//My Error fixed code
                  _webViewController!.loadUrl(
                    urlRequest: URLRequest(
                      url: Uri.parse("https://google.com/"), //Correct url
                    ),
                  );
                },
                label: const Text("Load Correct URL"),
                icon: const Icon(Icons.check),
              ),
              ElevatedButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {
                  _webViewController!.loadUrl(
                    urlRequest: URLRequest(
                      url: Uri.parse("https://google.com/404"), //Wrong url
                    ),
                  );
                },
                label: const Text("Load Wrong URL"),
                icon: const Icon(Icons.close),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        onWillPop: () async {
          //If website can go back page
          if (await _webViewController!.canGoBack()) {
            await _webViewController!.goBack();
            return false;
          } else {
            //Double pressed to exit app
            return _backPressed.exit(context);
          }
        });
  }
}
```

[image: Screenshoot]